# Excel keep 1st three rows and delete rest of duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-2010, delete-row

I have 20K data sheet that contain multiple duplicates for column 1. I need to keep 1st three duplicates for column 1 for each number and delete rest of it.

[image]

I need to keep the yellow highlighted and delete the rest of it.

Comment: It looks like you need to keep the first three duplicates and delete the rest of them.

Comment: yes, how to do that !!

Comment: Highlight the 4th and 5th row and hit the delete key.

Comment: haha this is a 20K data file and each number has different number of duplicates

Comment: I would go with some VBA in that case.

Comment: can you please suggest a solution for this !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109096/discussion-between-niranga-jayakody-and-jnevill).

Comment: You should [edit] your question to detail exactly what you're trying to do, along with an explanation of why you're having trouble with this and what you've already tried. (No one likes posting an answer only to hear that the OP has already tried their suggestion.)

Comment: do you actually need to delete the rows (this would required a VBA approach)?  Can a new list of data be generated?  Can additional columns of information be added that would allow the use of the build in filter function?

Comment: yes, new list of data world be fine. The exact requirement is i need to count the no of msg(column b) with respect to column 1(i can do that by using =countif()). But when counting i only need to take 1st three numbers (column 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, going the VBA route, you'll need to loop through each row in your tab and test the value to see if it's a duplicate, if it's a duplicate then you'll increase a counter variable and once that counter variable hits 3 you start deleting rows.

This is a little complicated if you haven't worked with VBA. Please take some time to play with the code and understand it. I've written comments in it to help out.

```
Sub keepFirstThreeDuplicates()
    Dim workingRow As Integer
    Dim currentDup As String
    Dim dupCounter As Integer
    Dim wsheet As Worksheet

    'change this to your tab name
    Set wsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'loop through every row just guessing that your data starts at row 1 (A1) and goes to 50000 (A50000)
    For workingRow = 1 To 50000

        If workingRow = 1 Then 'we are at the first row, so grab the value and set dupCounter to 1
            currentDup = wsheet.Cells(workingRow, 1).Value 'Assuming column 1, so this is Cell A1
            dupCounter = 1
        ElseIf currentDup = wsheet.Cells(workingRow, 1).Value Then 'we have another duplicate
            If dupCounter = 3 Then 'We already have three duplicates, so delete the row, and set the row back one (because we deleted the row)
                wsheet.Rows(workingRow).Delete
                workingRow = workingRow - 1
            Else
                dupCounter = dupCounter + 1
            End If
        Else 'We are at a new value, so grab the value and set dupCounter to 1
            currentDup = wsheet.Cells(workingRow, 1).Value
            dupCounter = 1
        End If

        'exit the for loop if we hit a blank
        If currentDup = "" Then Exit For
    Next workingRow

End Sub
```

If you are super new to VBA, to use this code:

1. While in your workbook, hit Ctrl+F11 to get to the Visual Basic
   Editor (VBE)
2. Your workbook will be called a "VBAProject" in the VBAProject panel.
   Right click on it and select Insert>>Module
3. Double click your new module "Module1" to open it.
4. Paste in this code.
5. To run it, click somewhere in the code and hit the play button up
   top (or F5 on your keyboard). Make sure you edit the code to suit
   the needs of your workbook like changing the tab name to your tab.
   Also make sure to back up your workbook before running it as this
   will delete rows and you won't be able to undo.

Lastly, this is just one way to do it. It's not meant to 100% address your needs since I'm guessing at number of rows, which column your data is in, that the data is already sorted by your duplicate column, and other whatnot. This is just to point you in a solid direction in VBA. It worked on my test workbook for a fake list I created in Column A of a fresh workbook.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach without using VBA and does not require your Data to be sorted is to create a third column of data where you simply count the number of times a Sender ID has happened.

```
Assuming:
Sender is column B
Message is column C
Count will be new column C
Row 1 is a header row
Data starts in row 2
```

in D2 place the the follow formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)
```

Copy that down the entire column.

Select a select within your data or in your header row.

Right click on the header in D1 and select filter and from the fly out select by cells value.  (Your data may disappear but its just hiding)

Left click on the funnel icon in the D1 and select number filter.  From the fly out select less than or equal to and place the number 3 in the top right box.

Select your original 2 columns of data and copy and paste to a new sheet and you will only have the first three entries in the new list.

Comment: now if you do not want to copy and paste the data there are ways of counting occurrences of data while ignoring hidden rows, but that is a difference question.