# Excel AverageIF function: Taking only first X rows meeting the criteria

Tags: excel, average

I have a column of criteria, and a column of data values. I can use `AverageIF` excel function to average the data values that meet the criteria. But what I want to do is, in addition to this criteria, have an additional control - to only take the average of the first 3 (X) rows meeting the criteria.

Is this possible? I've considered `AverageIFS`, but I'm not sure how to include a 'Count' or 'First' or 'Top' function into the second criteria.

Comment: some recently posted a question on how to make a list containing only the first three occurrence that matched a criteria.  I would follow what they did in that post to trim your list down, then do you average if routine.

Comment: [Here is that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612287/excel-keep-1st-three-rows-and-delete-rest-of-duplicates/36612693#comment60822229_36612693)

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ROW($A$2:$A$20)=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$20=1,ROW($A$2:$A$20)),{1,2,3}),$B$2:$B$20))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly excel will put `{}` around the formula.

The `{1,2,3}` denotes the first three in order from top to bottom.  It can be changed to what every is wanted like `{1,2,3,4}` for the first 4.

I used the criterion of `1` in this part `$A$2:$A$20=1` change the 1 to whatever you want.  You can also use a cell reference instead, if you want to put the criterion inside a cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the ideas and help. In the end I made a macro/function to do the job. `r` is the Range to look for the `match` in, and `count` determines how many of the matching results (taken from Range `averagerange`) to average. The `Ascending` parameter hasn't been implemented yet, but would allow which direction to select the the matching values (ie., the first/top X, or last/bottom X). `match` is overly simplified in that it only find equal values (not `<` or `>` or `!=` etc). If `count` is larger than the number of matches, then the average of the matching values is returned.

```
Public Function PF_AverageIF(r As range, match As Variant, averagerange As range, count As Long, Ascending As Boolean) As Double
    'Debug.Print ("PF_AverageIF called")
    'Debug.Print ("range = " & r.Address)
    'Debug.Print ("criteria = " & criteria)
    'Debug.Print ("averagerange = " & averagerange.Address)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim total As Double                 

    For Row = 1 To r.Rows.count
        'Debug.Print ("=>" & r(Row, 1))
        If (r(Row, 1).Value = match) Then
            'Debug.Print ("........" & averagerange(Row, 1))
            'Debug.Print ("^^^^")
            total = total + averagerange(Row, 1)
            i = i + 1
            If (count > 0) And (i = count) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next Row

    PF_AverageIF = total / i

End Function
```